# Query for PostgreSQL Server status variable?

Tags: postgresql

In my project i want to collect PostgreSQL server's performance counter. For that i want query to collect it from the database. i am new to postgreSQL. when i am searching, i got something like,

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_database
```

but when i am use this in java in the following manner, Here Map_PostgreSQL is a hashmap.

```
            while(rs.next())
            {
                Counter_Name.add(rs.getString(1).trim());
                Map_PostgreSQL.put(rs.getString(1).trim(), rs.getString(2));

            }
```

I got output like

```
{12024=template0, 1=template1, 12029=postgres}
```

What is the actual query to collect its status variables like "**SHOW GLOBAL STATUS**" in MySQL.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

1st, try to launch the sql query in your PostgreSQL Shell to see exactly which data are returned and how it is organised in rows and columns.

You'll see that the hashmap keys are your datid (database ids) and the values are your databases names.

I think you assumed that statistics were structured in "rows" whereas they are structured in columns.

Don't forget : PostgreSQL is a database server which means it can handle several databases (and in fact, it has several databases because some of them are already created such as the 'postgres' database itself - which Postgres (the server) uses internally, or 'template0').

By launching :

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_database;
```

You're asking the server to return statistics for every databases (provided you're allowed to get them)

If you want to only have stats for your own database, do :

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_database WHERE datname='your_database_name';
```

Hope this helped

Comment: you are correct. but i want statictics for whole server not a particular Database. I want to monitor PostgreSQl fully, that means its every counter values. Is there any query to monitor this?

Comment: Did you run the 1st query in your PostgreSQL shell ? The query is ok, it's your java code that doesn't extract what you want.

Comment: can you tell me should i give database name in connection string in java? Or can i got it directly? now i just tried "Select * from pg_stat_bgwriter" in Sql Shell(plsql). it shows, come values like buffers_alloc. but without giving database name, if i use like this means "con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://"+Host+":"+Port , Username , Password);" i got {6=0} this alone? please cler my doubt @Raphaël Braud

Comment: I'm unfortunately not fluent in Java. But the 1st java code you wrote showed that you had accesses to all statistics (cause you got : {12024=template0, 1=template1, 12029=postgres}), it's just the way you parsed results that is wrong imho, compare {12024=template0, 1=template1, 12029=postgres} with psql output to see that you indeed got some of the psql results but not the ones you expected because of bad "parsing"

Comment: @Mohamed : did you finally fix your issue ? Was it java code related as I assumed ?

Comment: finally i find the query for all counters. but each have individual query to fetch from database. Anyway thanks to spend your valuable time @Raphaël Braud